# Como validar upload de vários arquivos no laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho a seguinte regra de validação no controller:

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'nome' => 'required|max:255',
        'valor' => 'required|numeric|min: 0',
        'imagens' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:1000',
        'descricao' => 'max: 255',
        'finalidade' => 'max: 255',
        'area' => 'required|numeric|min:0',
        'quartos' => 'required|numeric|min:0',
        'banheiros' => 'required|numeric|min:0',
        'garagens' => 'required|numeric|min:0',
        'suites' => 'required|numeric|min:0',
        'imagens.*' => 'required|mimes: jpeg,jpg,bmp,png'
    ]);
```

Com um input file da seguinte maneira:

```
<input type="file" name="imagens[]" multiple value="{{ old('imagens') }}" id="" class="form-control">
```

Mesmo quando eu faço um upload de 2 arquivos .jpg a validação falha, dizendo que o formato tem que ser jpg.

Acho que a validação deve ser feita arquivo por arquivo. Alguém consegue fazer isso?

Comment: Já tentou removendo essa linha `'imagens' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:1000',` e deixando apenas essa `'imagens.*' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,bmp,png'` ?

Comment: Sim.

Na verdade eu não havia visto que estava duplicado.

Vi agora, mas mesmo removendo, aponta individualmente que o arquivo 1 e 2 devem ter o formato jpg. Estranho, porque eles estão neste formato...